# How can I keep all objects updated in this OOP example?

Tags: python, object, oop

I don't know exactly how to explain it, but I'll try my best.

Here is a simple OOP example where you create players to kill a dragon. The point is to assign to each player a specific amount of damage to inflict on a dragon, in order to kill it.

For instance, if a dragon has 200 health and 2 players are chosen to attack it, the players will be assigned to deal 100 damage each.

Here's the structure of the OOP:

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.damage_to_deal = {} #Format: {'dragon': damage to deal to him}

class Dragon:

    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.number_of_players_attacking = 0

    #Add a player as someone who'll attack this dragon
    def add_player(self, player):
        self.number_of_players_attacking += 1
        player.damage_to_deal[self.name] = self.calculate_partition_damage()

    def calculate_partition_damage(self):
        if self.number_of_players_attacking == 0:
            self.partition_damage = 0
        else:
            self.partition_damage = self.health/self.number_of_players_attacking #health / number of players = damage to do for each player
        return self.partition_damage
```

Here are manipulations I'm testing:

```
#Create 3 players
player_A = Player(name='Josh')
player_B = Player(name='Steven')
player_C = Player(name='Robert')

#Create 2 Dragons
dragon_A = Dragon(name='Gamacial', health=475)
dragon_B = Dragon(name='Nibiru', health=150)

#All 3 players will attack the dragon A
dragon_A.add_player(player_A)
dragon_A.add_player(player_B)
dragon_A.add_player(player_C)

#Only player A and B will attack dragon B
dragon_B.add_player(player_A)
dragon_B.add_player(player_B)

#The damage each player will have to... {'to this dragon': x damage} to kill the dragons
print(f'{player_A.name} will have to do: {player_A.damage_to_deal}')
print(f'{player_B.name} will have to do: {player_B.damage_to_deal}')
print(f'{player_C.name} will have to do: {player_C.damage_to_deal}')
```

This prints the following:

```
Josh will have to do: {'Gamacial': 475.0, 'Nibiru': 150.0}
Steven will have to do: {'Gamacial': 237.5, 'Nibiru': 75.0}
Robert will have to do: {'Gamacial': 158.33333333333334}
```

The issue is that, since Josh is the first player to be tasked with killing Gamacial and Nibiru, he's assigned to deal the full damage on these dragons, despite the fact that Steven and Robert are also tasked with killing that dragon.(Same issue with the dragon Nibiru).

In other words, it'll always be the last player that'll have the actual correct damage to deal, while the others will always be one step behind the calculation because they've been assigned the task before taking into count the next player.

It should therefore print:

```
Josh will have to do: {'Gamacial': 158.33333333333334, 'Nibiru': 75.0}
Steven will have to do: {'Gamacial': 158.33333333333334, 'Nibiru': 75.0}
Robert will have to do: {'Gamacial': 158.33333333333334}
```

Is there any way I keep ALL players in sync with each other? So after Steven gets assigned the same dragon as Josh, Josh gets updated, etc.?

Comment: "it'll always be the last player that'll have the actual correct damage to deal" Well, **why does** that player have the correct amount? (Hint: where is `self.partition_damage` calculated? That calculation involves a division, correct? What is the code dividing by?) Now, can you think of a way to make sure that value is correct before calculating the damage? (Hint: what causes that value to change? Can you think of a way to make all those changes happen, before the damage calculations? What if you used a different approach to call `calculate_partition_damage`?)

Comment: Secondary hint: think about what your methods are supposed to do, *according to how you named them*. Does it make sense, logically, that "calculating partition damage" *is a part of the process of* assigning a player to the team killing that dragon? Or is it something that you do *after* you have figured out what the team is?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel
I guess I'm having trouble conceptually implementing the part where I "figured out what the team is", because hypothetically, the team could always have players added or removed from it, so calculating damage would be some external function (outside of any class) that is always ran at the end of the script. Is that what you're suggesting?

Comment: "hypothetically, the team could always have players added or removed from it" Can that happen while the damage is calculated? if it happens after you report the `damage_to_deal`, does it matter? "so calculating damage would be some external function". No. Continue to use the `calculate_partition_damage` method. Do not call it from within `add_player`. Instead, use it from the outside code, after you finish adding players. You will notice, after this, that the `.damage_to_deal` attribute is useless. (You will eventually notice that the entire design of the class does not make a lot of sense.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**maybe you should calculate later, after all player registered to dragons:**

```
class Player:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.damage_to_deal = {} #Format: {'dragon': damage to deal to him}

    def deal_damage(self):
        for name in self.damage_to_deal:
            target = self.damage_to_deal[name] 
            self.damage_to_deal[name] = target.health / target.number_of_players_attacking
        return self.damage_to_deal 
        
class Dragon:

    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health
        self.number_of_players_attacking = 0

    #Add a player as someone who'll attack this dragon
    def add_player(self, player):
        self.number_of_players_attacking += 1
        player.damage_to_deal[self.name] = self #  calculate later
```

register:

```
#Create 3 players
player_A = Player(name='Josh')
player_B = Player(name='Steven')
player_C = Player(name='Robert')

#Create 2 Dragons
dragon_A = Dragon(name='Gamacial', health=475)
dragon_B = Dragon(name='Nibiru', health=150)

#All 3 players will attack the dragon A
dragon_A.add_player(player_A)
dragon_A.add_player(player_B)
dragon_A.add_player(player_C)

#Only player A and B will attack dragon B
dragon_B.add_player(player_A)
dragon_B.add_player(player_B)
```

then calculate:

```
#The damage each player will have to... {'to this dragon': x damage} to kill the dragons
print(f'{player_A.name} will have to do: {player_A.deal_damage()}')
print(f'{player_B.name} will have to do: {player_B.deal_damage()}')
print(f'{player_C.name} will have to do: {player_C.deal_damage()}')
```

Comment: That works, thanks. So the function has to be called outside the classes, but why is player.damage_to_deal[self.name] = self? What is "self" in and of itself and why does it work?

Comment: that "self" is current dragon that being added to a player targets (temporary value so player will remember), so when later we call deal_damage(), we know which dragon to attack, you replace the value with the amount of damage the player need to do.

Comment: maybe you can add to another attribute: player.target_list[self.name] = self